# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: i (for-loop problem)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I made a break from my react native project for about 3 weeks and now I came back and wanted to work on it, unfortunaly the app doesnt even render the first screen components. I already figured out what the problem is, Im just totaly confused what is going on:

```
    var chatkeys = [];
    var partnerkeys = [];
    var contactsDATA = [];

    await firebase.database().
    ref(`users/${PersonalId}/chats`).
    once('value').
    then(snapshot =>{
        for (i in snapshot.val()){//pulling all chatcodes out of database and pushing into chatkeys
            chatkeys.push(snapshot.val()[i]);
        };
    });
```

The problem is located in the for-loop. Here is the error Im receiving:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: i]
>
> - node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13
>   in tryCallOne
> - node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6
>   in __callImmediates
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6
>   in __guard$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10
>   in __guard
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4
>   in flushedQueue
>
> - [native code]:null in flushedQueue
> - [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

How can JS not find the variable "i"? I never told JS to search for "i" - it's just supposed to be a counter to loop through the whole snapshot.val() array. What is going on here?

Comment: Did you try declaring it, e.g., `for (let i in ...)`? (I'd also lean away from using `var` in general.)

Comment: mixing `await` and `.then` is an anti-pattern. use `for..of` instead of `for..in`. don't use variables without a `let` or `const` declration. Try `let snapshot = await firebase.database().ref(\`users/${PersonalId}/chats\`).once('value'); for (let i of snapshot.val()) ...`

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `i` is not defined. reading your code, I can see that `i` inside your for loop declaration may be missing the `let i` variable.

Have you tried `for (let i in snapshot.val()){`

Answer (score -1):

`i` is not declared in the scope.
Try

```
for (let i in snapshot.val()){//pulling all chatcodes out of database and pushing into chatkeys
            chatkeys.push(snapshot.val()[i]);
        };
```

OR

```
let i;
for (i in snapshot.val()){//pulling all chatcodes out of database and pushing into chatkeys
            chatkeys.push(snapshot.val()[i]);
        };
```